# Return Acknoledgement to Socket Client After Recieving its data

Tags: php

I am trying to receive data through a socket connection as a stream from a GPS Device.

I am unable to return acknowledgement to a socket client sending the stream to the server to confirm that I have received the data on the server. This acknowledgement has to be in raw packets.

These are the instructions from the documentation:
[image: These are the instructions from the documentation]

My other challenge is that for me to receive the data from the client connecting to the IP and PORT example (`tcp://127.0.0.1:9123`) I have to run this command `php get-socketdata.php` in the terminal.

Below is my code on how I receive the stream connection (it's working well):

```
$server = stream_socket_server('tcp://127.0.0.1:9123');
$socket = stream_socket_accept($server);
$EncodedData = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 1500);
$Device_DataPackets = bin2hex($EncodedData);
```

However one the data starts coming in the connection just drops. I am running this on a Linux VM on AWS.

To return acknowledgement to the socket client:

```
if (socket_write($socket, $Confirm, 6) === false) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg");
}else{ echo 'great data sent to socket client'; }
```

This is where I break from. The acknowledgement is not sent to the device.

Comment: what the value of `$Configr` in 2nd snippet? and why you mix stream_* and socket_stream_*?

Comment: HI @MarcinOrlowski 

this is the value : $Confirm = pack("H*", "0002640113BC");

what is the best way to do it without mixing them up

i want to use stream_socket_*

Comment: is there a way i can use stream_socket_client() to respond to the connected client ? can this work if i have more than 2 devices connected at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing `socket_*` and `stream_socket_*` which is not needed. I switched to use just `socket_*`. Here is goes the `server.php`:

```php
<?php
$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($server, '127.0.0.1', 9123);
socket_listen($server);

while(true) {
    $socket = socket_accept($server);
    if (!$socket) {
        die('Socked accept failed.');
    }

    // receive data
    $EncodedData = socket_read($socket, 1500);
    $Device_DataPackets = bin2hex($EncodedData);
    print("Received: {$EncodedData}" . PHP_EOL);

    // send ACK
    $raw_ack_packet = hex2bin('0002640113bc');
    $sentBytes = socket_write($socket, $raw_ack_packet, strlen($raw_ack_packet));
    $expectedSentBytes = strlen($raw_ack_packet);
    if ($sentBytes === false || $sentBytes !== $expectedSentBytes) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Couldn't send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg");
    }

    socket_close($socket);
}

socket_close($server);
```

As I have no GPS you talk about, I made one (`client.php`) for testing purposes:

```php
<?php
$ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9123;
$sample_data = "Some sample GPS data";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, $ip_address, $port);
socket_write($socket, $sample_data, strlen($sample_data));
$ack_packet = socket_read($socket, 1024);
echo "Received ACK packet: " . bin2hex($ack_packet) . PHP_EOL;
socket_close($socket);
```

Run both (in right order :) and you could see:

```bash
$ php server.php
Received: Some sample GPS data
$
```

and

```bash
$ php client.php
Received ACK packet: 0002640113bc
$
```

[image]

Comment: thank-you it has worked for me. Now one last thing i have left is that when i run the command " php server.php " the connection just drops after receiving the data from the client, i want the stream data to keep coming its the client device that is supposed to terminate the connection not the server( Note : the data is coming in as a stream it should not stop coming unless the device stops its-self )

Comment: See edited answer. I simply wrapped the main part in infinite `while(true)` loop

Comment: PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): accept failed: Connection timed out is the error that am getting even wen its in a while(true){} loop

Comment: there's no `stream_socket_accept()` in my code.